# How to set TFS Git Permissions

Tags: tfs

I am trying to set GIT repository permissions using the GroupAndPermissions.xml in the TFS process template. IS it possible ??  It gives an error saying GIT is not a valid class.

[image: GroupAndPermission.xml]

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is expected. You can't set GIT repository permissions in the GroupAndPermissions.xml file. Only the following values are valid for Class:

- **NAMESPACE**: Specifies collection-level permissions.
- **PROJECT**: Specifies project-level permissions.
- **CSS_NODE**: Specifies permissions for viewing and managing area paths
  for a team project.
- **ITERATION_NODE**: Specifies permissions for viewing and managing
  iteration paths for a team project.

To set GIT repository permissions, you need go to TFS Web Access `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/CollectionName/GitProjectName/_admin/_versioncontrol`to set permissions across all Git repositories. More details, check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#git-repository